# How to call image and .mp3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a method that will load songs using javascript.

```
function loadSong(song) {
    title.textContent = song.displayname;
    artist.textContent = song.artist;
    music.src = 'music/${song.name}.mp3'; //is not seeing the song.name
    image.src = '/img/${song.name}.jpg';  // is not seeing the image too
}
```

My vscode doesn't see '/img/${song.name}.jpg' and 'music/${song.name}.mp3' . How do i call the music and image.

My vscode doesn't see **'/img/${song.name}.jpg' and 'music/${song.name}.mp3'** . How do i call the music and image.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't see"? Did you mean to use backticks ( ` ) instead of single quotes ( ' ) for your strings?

Comment: @Xerillio thank you for your response. I'm trying to call the image and music using 'img/${song.name}.jpg' but is not seeing the image. img is the folder where i store the images.

Comment: But what does "doesn't see" and "is not seeing the image" mean?

Comment: Yes.  I have changed it to music.src = `music/${song.name}.mp3`;

Comment: music.src = (`music/${song.name}.mp3`);

Comment: But not playing

Comment: what do you mean "call the music" or "call the image"?

Comment: I am working on a web music player with javascript. I have the images and music in different folder in my vs code .

Comment: Hello guys, I was able to figure it out. It was my macbook pro keyboard. I appreciate you all. thank you guys.

Comment: insert in your html file first of all and run it, if the ran location works copy that location and insert in js